# Remove a higher quantity from stock according to a variation

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i'm gonna sell wine online and i have a little problem,
Let's contextualise, i have 1 product with 2 variation :

- 1 Bottle (10$)
- 1 Box = 6 Bottle (58$)

what I would like to see is that when buying a box, the stock of the main product be reduced by 6, and by 1 if he buy a bottle

If you have any plugin (free or premium) or snippets or help i will be very grateful

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can refer to https://gist.github.com/JeroenSormani/f88fc05957773cae04aaa71718cfeff0

Answer (score 0):

Thank to [Akshat](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/114978/akshat) who gave me the first step [here](https://gist.github.com/JeroenSormani/f88fc05957773cae04aaa71718cfeff0), after searching more i found [this](https://jeroensormani.com/custom-stock-quantity-reduction/) and it's was exactly what i wanted
I hope this can help some other